# Turn assignment into an if statement

Tags: javascript

Just wanting to know how I could make an if statement from this:

```
var str = value.flight;
var n = str.includes("RLK");
```

I have tried

```
if (n =='true'){
    ///my function
}
else
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: str.includes returns a boolean true or false  if(n) {}  or if (n === true) {}

Comment: Try a real boolean, like `true`, or just test for `if (n)`, instead of a string with content "true".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n` is not a string, but a boolean. You need to check that `n` is `true`. You can use the following expression `n === true`, but it's a bad practice, so simplify `if (n) {...`

```js
var value = { flight: '123 RLK' };
var str = value.flight;
var n = str.includes('RLK');

if (n) {
  console.log('includes');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`if (n == true)` - remove the quote marks. `n` is a boolean value, so you have to test for that, not a string which happens to read as the word "true".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes has the details of the `includes` method, including the return type.

Here's a working example:

```js
var value = {
  flight: '123 RLK'
};
var str = value.flight;
var n = str.includes('RLK');

if (n == true) {
  alert('n was true');
}
```

Comment: @ADdyson any idea on how I can read a value the value being value.flight? (coming from json file)

Comment: @KieranGeraghty sorry I don't know what you mean? In the code above `str` already takes on the value of `value.flight` on the line `var str = value.flight;`. If that's not what you mean you'll have to explain a little more clearly what you're getting at.

Comment: I have this: $.when($.getJSON(url)).done(function(data) {
    $.each(data.aircraft, function(i, value) { It is turning a value from JSON file into value.flight but when I do str == value.flight it says "value is not defined".

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), the includes function returns a boolean, not a string.  So you would instead write:

```
var str = value.flight;
var n = str.includes("RLK");
if (n) {
  //code here
}
```